# PIC10F200 coding/setup issue

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, mplab

**What I use**

1. Arduino Uno (as a power supplier)
2. PicKit 5
3. MPLAB X IDE 6.15
4. PIC10F200

**What I know :**

1. The OPTIONS on some pins can overwrite the TRIS states (I somewhat read the datasheet but it gets me tired to jump back and forward);
2. What 0b00001000 means (somewhat).

**The project**

I'm trying to program a PIC10F200 for a simple project, basically:
GP1 gets power flowing into it or not, based on that information GP0 either turns the LED ON or keeps it OFF.

I have used this code to check that the pins are not shorted :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <PIC10F200.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

// CONFIG
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protect (Code protection off)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // Master Clear Enable (GP3/MCLR pin fuction is digital I/O, MCLR internally tied to VDD)

void main(void)

{
    OPTION = 0b11011111;
    TRISGPIO = 0b00001000;
    GPIO = 0b00000111;
}
```

**What I need help with**

- Explain some more basic commands for my lack of embedded knowledge;
- Maybe the circuit is built wrong, suggest options.

So after that check, this was **the code I created** (I don't understand also what is wrong when posting the code so... I'm sorry.):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>

// CONFIG
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protect (Code protection off)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF 
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void main()
{
    OPTION = 0b11011111;
    TRISGPIO = 0b00000010;
    GPIO = 0b00000000;
    
    while(1)
    {
        if(GP1 == '1')
        {
            GP0 = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            GP0 = '1';
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Attempt of diagram]

**Background** (If you ask yourself why I'm so unintelligent...)

- Lack of knowledge on electronics;
- Rusty on physics;
- Study univ (electrical engineering - the irony... you may say...);
- Teachers are not very bright neither helpful ("You should worry about failing exams, not this");
- Can't spend extra time to work and earn money (At least I would've done something productive so it helps me live?);
- Can't spend extra time to research or read a lot (I lose 5~6h traveling daily - no, I can't watch youtube or listen to audio logs );
- Most of youtube videos don't help (outdated aka: 3 years ago - assembly / other microcontrollers);
- Didn't get to learn Assembly (also the compiler does not support Assembly language anymore?! - I think).

Try working project, got no working project.

[edit]

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <PIC10F200.h>

// CONFIG
#pragma config WDTE = OFF 
#pragma config CP = OFF 
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF
// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.
#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void main() {
  OPTION = 0b11011111;
  TRISGPIO = 0b00000010;
  GPIO = 0b00000000;
  while (1) {
    if (GP1 == '1') {
      GP0 = '0'; // Turn off the LED
    } else {
      GP0 = '1'; // Turn on the LED
    }
  }
}
```

Header file :

```c
// Register: INDF
#define INDF INDF
extern volatile unsigned char           INDF                __at(0x000);
#ifndef _LIB_BUILD
asm("INDF equ 00h");
#endif
// bitfield definitions
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned INDF                   :8;
    };
} INDFbits_t;
extern volatile INDFbits_t INDFbits __at(0x000);
// bitfield macros
#define _INDF_INDF_POSN                                     0x0
#define _INDF_INDF_POSITION                                 0x0
#define _INDF_INDF_SIZE                                     0x8
#define _INDF_INDF_LENGTH                                   0x8
#define _INDF_INDF_MASK                                     0xFF

// Register: TMR0
#define TMR0 TMR0
extern volatile unsigned char           TMR0                __at(0x001);
#ifndef _LIB_BUILD
asm("TMR0 equ 01h");
#endif
// bitfield definitions
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned TMR0                   :8;
    };
} TMR0bits_t;
extern volatile TMR0bits_t TMR0bits __at(0x001);
// bitfield macros
#define _TMR0_TMR0_POSN                                     0x0
#define _TMR0_TMR0_POSITION                                 0x0
#define _TMR0_TMR0_SIZE                                     0x8
#define _TMR0_TMR0_LENGTH                                   0x8
#define _TMR0_TMR0_MASK                                     0xFF

// Register: PCL
#define PCL PCL
extern volatile unsigned char           PCL                 __at(0x002);
#ifndef _LIB_BUILD
asm("PCL equ 02h");
#endif
// bitfield definitions
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned PCL                    :8;
    };
} PCLbits_t;
extern volatile PCLbits_t PCLbits __at(0x002);
// bitfield macros
#define _PCL_PCL_POSN                                       0x0
#define _PCL_PCL_POSITION                                   0x0
#define _PCL_PCL_SIZE                                       0x8
#define _PCL_PCL_LENGTH                                     0x8
#define _PCL_PCL_MASK                                       0xFF

// Register: STATUS
#define STATUS STATUS
extern volatile unsigned char           STATUS              __at(0x003);
#ifndef _LIB_BUILD
asm("STATUS equ 03h");
#endif
// bitfield definitions
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned C                      :1;
        unsigned DC                     :1;
        unsigned Z                      :1;
        unsigned nPD                    :1;
        unsigned nTO                    :1;
        unsigned                        :2;
        unsigned GPWUF                  :1;
    };
    struct {
        unsigned CARRY                  :1;
        unsigned                        :1;
        unsigned ZERO                   :1;
    };
} STATUSbits_t;
extern volatile STATUSbits_t STATUSbits __at(0x003);
// bitfield macros
#define _STATUS_C_POSN                                      0x0
#define _STATUS_C_POSITION                                  0x0
#define _STATUS_C_SIZE                                      0x1
#define _STATUS_C_LENGTH                                    0x1
#define _STATUS_C_MASK                                      0x1
#define _STATUS_DC_POSN                                     0x1
#define _STATUS_DC_POSITION                                 0x1
#define _STATUS_DC_SIZE                                     0x1
#define _STATUS_DC_LENGTH                                   0x1
#define _STATUS_DC_MASK                                     0x2
#define _STATUS_Z_POSN                                      0x2
#define _STATUS_Z_POSITION                                  0x2
#define _STATUS_Z_SIZE                                      0x1
#define _STATUS_Z_LENGTH                                    0x1
#define _STATUS_Z_MASK                                      0x4
#define _STATUS_nPD_POSN                                    0x3
#define _STATUS_nPD_POSITION                                0x3
#define _STATUS_nPD_SIZE                                    0x1
#define _STATUS_nPD_LENGTH                                  0x1
#define _STATUS_nPD_MASK                                    0x8
#define _STATUS_nTO_POSN                                    0x4
#define _STATUS_nTO_POSITION                                0x4
#define _STATUS_nTO_SIZE                                    0x1
#define _STATUS_nTO_LENGTH                                  0x1
#define _STATUS_nTO_MASK                                    0x10
#define _STATUS_GPWUF_POSN                                  0x7
#define _STATUS_GPWUF_POSITION                              0x7
#define _STATUS_GPWUF_SIZE                                  0x1
#define _STATUS_GPWUF_LENGTH                                0x1
#define _STATUS_GPWUF_MASK                                  0x80
#define _STATUS_CARRY_POSN                                  0x0
#define _STATUS_CARRY_POSITION                              0x0
#define _STATUS_CARRY_SIZE                                  0x1
#define _STATUS_CARRY_LENGTH                                0x1
#define _STATUS_CARRY_MASK                                  0x1
#define _STATUS_ZERO_POSN                                   0x2
#define _STATUS_ZERO_POSITION                               0x2
#define _STATUS_ZERO_SIZE                                   0x1
#define _STATUS_ZERO_LENGTH                                 0x1
#define _STATUS_ZERO_MASK                                   0x4

// Register: FSR
#define FSR FSR
extern volatile unsigned char           FSR                 __at(0x004);
#ifndef _LIB_BUILD
asm("FSR equ 04h");
#endif
// bitfield definitions
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned FSR                    :8;
    };
} FSRbits_t;
extern volatile FSRbits_t FSRbits __at(0x004);
// bitfield macros
#define _FSR_FSR_POSN                                       0x0
#define _FSR_FSR_POSITION                                   0x0
#define _FSR_FSR_SIZE                                       0x8
#define _FSR_FSR_LENGTH                                     0x8
#define _FSR_FSR_MASK                                       0xFF

// Register: OSCCAL
#define OSCCAL OSCCAL
extern volatile unsigned char           OSCCAL              __at(0x005);
#ifndef _LIB_BUILD
asm("OSCCAL equ 05h");
#endif
// bitfield definitions
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned FOSC4                  :1;
        unsigned CAL                    :7;
    };
    struct {
        unsigned                        :1;
        unsigned CAL0                   :1;
        unsigned CAL1                   :1;
        unsigned CAL2                   :1;
        unsigned CAL3                   :1;
        unsigned CAL4                   :1;
        unsigned CAL5                   :1;
        unsigned CAL6                   :1;
    };
} OSCCALbits_t;
extern volatile OSCCALbits_t OSCCALbits __at(0x005);
// bitfield macros
#define _OSCCAL_FOSC4_POSN                                  0x0
#define _OSCCAL_FOSC4_POSITION                              0x0
#define _OSCCAL_FOSC4_SIZE                                  0x1
#define _OSCCAL_FOSC4_LENGTH                                0x1
#define _OSCCAL_FOSC4_MASK                                  0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL_POSN                                    0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL_POSITION                                0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL_SIZE                                    0x7
#define _OSCCAL_CAL_LENGTH                                  0x7
#define _OSCCAL_CAL_MASK                                    0xFE
#define _OSCCAL_CAL0_POSN                                   0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL0_POSITION                               0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL0_SIZE                                   0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL0_LENGTH                                 0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL0_MASK                                   0x2
#define _OSCCAL_CAL1_POSN                                   0x2
#define _OSCCAL_CAL1_POSITION                               0x2
#define _OSCCAL_CAL1_SIZE                                   0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL1_LENGTH                                 0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL1_MASK                                   0x4
#define _OSCCAL_CAL2_POSN                                   0x3
#define _OSCCAL_CAL2_POSITION                               0x3
#define _OSCCAL_CAL2_SIZE                                   0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL2_LENGTH                                 0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL2_MASK                                   0x8
#define _OSCCAL_CAL3_POSN                                   0x4
#define _OSCCAL_CAL3_POSITION                               0x4
#define _OSCCAL_CAL3_SIZE                                   0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL3_LENGTH                                 0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL3_MASK                                   0x10
#define _OSCCAL_CAL4_POSN                                   0x5
#define _OSCCAL_CAL4_POSITION                               0x5
#define _OSCCAL_CAL4_SIZE                                   0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL4_LENGTH                                 0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL4_MASK                                   0x20
#define _OSCCAL_CAL5_POSN                                   0x6
#define _OSCCAL_CAL5_POSITION                               0x6
#define _OSCCAL_CAL5_SIZE                                   0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL5_LENGTH                                 0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL5_MASK                                   0x40
#define _OSCCAL_CAL6_POSN                                   0x7
#define _OSCCAL_CAL6_POSITION                               0x7
#define _OSCCAL_CAL6_SIZE                                   0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL6_LENGTH                                 0x1
#define _OSCCAL_CAL6_MASK                                   0x80

// Register: GPIO
#define GPIO GPIO
extern volatile unsigned char           GPIO                __at(0x006);
#ifndef _LIB_BUILD
asm("GPIO equ 06h");
#endif
// bitfield definitions
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned GP0                    :1;
        unsigned GP1                    :1;
        unsigned GP2                    :1;
        unsigned GP3                    :1;
    };
} GPIObits_t;
extern volatile GPIObits_t GPIObits __at(0x006);
// bitfield macros
#define _GPIO_GP0_POSN                                      0x0
#define _GPIO_GP0_POSITION                                  0x0
#define _GPIO_GP0_SIZE                                      0x1
#define _GPIO_GP0_LENGTH                                    0x1
#define _GPIO_GP0_MASK                                      0x1
#define _GPIO_GP1_POSN                                      0x1
#define _GPIO_GP1_POSITION                                  0x1
#define _GPIO_GP1_SIZE                                      0x1
#define _GPIO_GP1_LENGTH                                    0x1
#define _GPIO_GP1_MASK                                      0x2
#define _GPIO_GP2_POSN                                      0x2
#define _GPIO_GP2_POSITION                                  0x2
#define _GPIO_GP2_SIZE                                      0x1
#define _GPIO_GP2_LENGTH                                    0x1
#define _GPIO_GP2_MASK                                      0x4
#define _GPIO_GP3_POSN                                      0x3
#define _GPIO_GP3_POSITION                                  0x3
#define _GPIO_GP3_SIZE                                      0x1
#define _GPIO_GP3_LENGTH                                    0x1
#define _GPIO_GP3_MASK                                      0x8

// Register: OPTION
#define OPTION OPTION
extern volatile __control unsigned char OPTION              __at(0x000);

// Register: TRIS
#define TRIS TRIS
extern volatile __control unsigned char TRIS                __at(0x006);

// Register: TRISGPIO
#define TRISGPIO TRISGPIO
extern volatile __control unsigned char TRISGPIO            __at(0x006);

/*
 * OPTION bits
 */
#define                                 PS                  0x7
#define                                 PSA                 0x8
#define                                 T0SE                0x10
#define                                 T0CS                0x20
#define                                 nGPPU               0x40
#define                                 nGPWU               0x80
#define                                 PS0                 0x1
#define                                 PS1                 0x2
#define                                 PS2                 0x4

/*
 * Bit Definitions
 */
#define _DEPRECATED __attribute__((__deprecated__))
#ifndef BANKMASK
#define BANKMASK(addr) ((addr)&01Fh)
#endif
#define _BIT_ACCESS(r,b) ___mkstr(BANKMASK(r)) "," ___mkstr(b)
#ifndef PAGEMASK
#define PAGEMASK(addr) ((addr)&01FFh)
#endif
// OSCCAL<CAL0>
extern volatile __bit                   CAL0                __at(0x29); // @ (0x5 * 8 + 1)
#define                                 CAL0_bit            _BIT_ACCESS(OSCCAL,1)
// OSCCAL<CAL1>
extern volatile __bit                   CAL1                __at(0x2A); // @ (0x5 * 8 + 2)
#define                                 CAL1_bit            _BIT_ACCESS(OSCCAL,2)
// OSCCAL<CAL2>
extern volatile __bit                   CAL2                __at(0x2B); // @ (0x5 * 8 + 3)
#define                                 CAL2_bit            _BIT_ACCESS(OSCCAL,3)
// OSCCAL<CAL3>
extern volatile __bit                   CAL3                __at(0x2C); // @ (0x5 * 8 + 4)
#define                                 CAL3_bit            _BIT_ACCESS(OSCCAL,4)
// OSCCAL<CAL4>
extern volatile __bit                   CAL4                __at(0x2D); // @ (0x5 * 8 + 5)
#define                                 CAL4_bit            _BIT_ACCESS(OSCCAL,5)
// OSCCAL<CAL5>
extern volatile __bit                   CAL5                __at(0x2E); // @ (0x5 * 8 + 6)
#define                                 CAL5_bit            _BIT_ACCESS(OSCCAL,6)
// OSCCAL<CAL6>
extern volatile __bit                   CAL6                __at(0x2F); // @ (0x5 * 8 + 7)
#define                                 CAL6_bit            _BIT_ACCESS(OSCCAL,7)
// STATUS<CARRY>
extern volatile __bit                   CARRY               __at(0x18); // @ (0x3 * 8 + 0)
#define                                 CARRY_bit           _BIT_ACCESS(STATUS,0)
// STATUS<DC>
extern volatile __bit                   DC                  __at(0x19); // @ (0x3 * 8 + 1)
#define                                 DC_bit              _BIT_ACCESS(STATUS,1)
// OSCCAL<FOSC4>
extern volatile __bit                   FOSC4               __at(0x28); // @ (0x5 * 8 + 0)
#define                                 FOSC4_bit           _BIT_ACCESS(OSCCAL,0)
// GPIO<GP0>
extern volatile __bit                   GP0                 __at(0x30); // @ (0x6 * 8 + 0)
#define                                 GP0_bit             _BIT_ACCESS(GPIO,0)
// GPIO<GP1>
extern volatile __bit                   GP1                 __at(0x31); // @ (0x6 * 8 + 1)
#define                                 GP1_bit             _BIT_ACCESS(GPIO,1)
// GPIO<GP2>
extern volatile __bit                   GP2                 __at(0x32); // @ (0x6 * 8 + 2)
#define                                 GP2_bit             _BIT_ACCESS(GPIO,2)
// GPIO<GP3>
extern volatile __bit                   GP3                 __at(0x33); // @ (0x6 * 8 + 3)
#define                                 GP3_bit             _BIT_ACCESS(GPIO,3)
// STATUS<GPWUF>
extern volatile __bit                   GPWUF               __at(0x1F); // @ (0x3 * 8 + 7)
#define                                 GPWUF_bit           _BIT_ACCESS(STATUS,7)
// STATUS<ZERO>
extern volatile __bit                   ZERO                __at(0x1A); // @ (0x3 * 8 + 2)
#define                                 ZERO_bit            _BIT_ACCESS(STATUS,2)
// STATUS<nPD>
extern volatile __bit                   nPD                 __at(0x1B); // @ (0x3 * 8 + 3)
#define                                 nPD_bit             _BIT_ACCESS(STATUS,3)
// STATUS<nTO>
extern volatile __bit                   nTO                 __at(0x1C); // @ (0x3 * 8 + 4)
#define                                 nTO_bit             _BIT_ACCESS(STATUS,4)

#endif // _PIC10F200_H_
```

Comment: main code : 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <PIC10F200.h>

// CONFIG
#pragma config WDTE = OFF
#pragma config CP = OFF
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF  

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
void main() 
{
OPTION = 0b11011111;
TRISGPIO = 0b00000010;
GPIO = 0b00000000;
    while(1) {
   if(GP1 == '1') 
        {
 GP0 = '0'; // Turn off the LED
        } 
        else 
        {
 GP0 = '1'; // Turn on the LED}}}

Comment: `GP0 = '0';` sets GP0 to the ASCII value of the character `0`, i.e. 48. Probably not what you want. Likewise comparing `GP1 == '1'`, which is comparing GP1 with 49.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "_Explain some more basic commands for my lack of embedded knowledge;_": Please ask specific questions in separate posts. - "_Maybe the circuit is built wrong, suggest options._": Recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @thebusybee I will keep in mind the off-topic like mentions I do but I'll leave this post like this since I don't know if I should and what I should edit. It will be a reminder for my first ever try to reach out to a community for help.

Comment: Would you mind to [edit] your question and add the generated assembly? I'm curious how `GP1` is compiled. You can as well add the definition of it, straight from the respective header file.

Comment: Would gladly do if I knew how to make Disassembly accessible for the file.

Comment: ***I don't understand also what is wrong when posting the code so*** - The code as image, look, simple; it just makes it difficult to us to read, modify and rewrite your code in case of there is something to fix in it. Imagine that you wanna help another developer, and you wanna fix the bugs in his/her code. But there is no code, instead,  all in all is just an image! Would you attempt to rewrite all the code from scratch for someone you don't know at all? It is just an inconvenience for the community and it is discourged, that's all.

Comment: So how is going on with your code? Have you managed to improve it with the help of the 2 answers below or you still need help? Well there is too many questions for one post, makes it difficult to provide a right answer. Try to simplify your problem, and split the problems into multiple questions so that you can ask them in different posts if needed. In other words; help us to help you.

Comment: GP1 as an input should be high-impedance.  If you have _"power flowing into it"_ you are in trouble!  I presume you simply mean when the input is _high_?

Comment: @Kozmotronik , I have edited the post now, added code instead of leaving it a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

`GP1 == '1'` is nonsense.

- Do you really have macros `GP0`/`GP1` offering bit writes and reads both? I doubt that.
- `'1'` is character literal ("ASCII") equivalent to binary 00110001 and thus nonsense. Use `1`.

---

Assuming that you have a declared register `GPIO` then you should have bit masks such as these:

```
#define GP0 (1u << 0)
#define GP1 (1u << 1)
```

Or better yet name them `GPIO_GP0` etc to document which register they belong to.

---

Reading the register then becomes:

```c
if((GPIO & GPIO_GP0) > 0)
...
if((GPIO & GPIO_GP1) > 0)
```

The `> 0` part is necessary since when bit masking bit 0 we get 0x01 or 0x00. But when bit masking bit 1, we get 0x02 or 0x00. We do not get 1 or 0 straight out of the register.

---

Writing to the register:

```c
GPIO |= GPIO_GP0;  // set pin GP0 to 1
GPIO &= ~GPIO_GP0; // set pin GP0 to 0
```

All of this ought to be covered by the average bitwise operator book/tutorial. More details here: [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290GPIO_GP0)

Comment: I get the error : use of undeclared identifier 'GPIO_GP0' and 'GPIO_GP1'
So when I modify your 2 lines of command from 
    #define GP0 (1u << 0)    
and
    #define GP1 (1u << 1)    

to ->

    #define GPIO_GP1 (1u << 1)    
and
    #define GPIO_GP0 (1u << 1)    
i get the error : expression is not assignable.

Should I use :
    #pragma GPIO_GP0
#pragma GPIO_GP1    
to make them declarable variables ?

I'm sorry if it's ridiculously easy for seniors or experienced electronics engineers but bear with me.

Comment: @7oh2 It all depends on if you already have a register map in some provided header file or if you need to declare the registers yourself.

Comment: I will leave a provided header file , might attach it as a link since I don't know yet how the site works here.

Answer (score 0):

The main error is the usage of character literals (in apostrophes) instead of number literals (without apostrophes).

The value `'1'` is `0x31` = `0x00110001`, coded in ASCII, but you want `1`.

A second error is the usage of a struct member in place of a variable. Add `GPIObits.` in front of `GP0` and `GP1`.

Use this:

```c
    if (GPIObits.GP1 != 0) {
      GPIObits.GP0 = 0; // Turn off the LED
    } else {
      GPIObits.GP0 = 1; // Turn on the LED
    }
```

The comparison with zero works generally well, independent of how a bit is read and returned. A "high" level returned as `1` or `2` (or `1 << any_bit_offet`) is always not equal to zero.

---

*Additional note on the hardware and setup:*

The pin `GP1` does not measure "*power flowing into it or not*", it senses the voltage at it. But you do not provide any other levels than "floating" (switch open) or "high" (switch closed). Most probably "floating" is sensed as "high" because of the charge it holds.

Be aware that an floating input can sense any other level, and even catch electric fields like mains. You can experience any sequence of "low" and "high" read from the pin.

If you add an external pull-down resistor, you define the level while the switch is open. A value of some kiloohms suffices.

Or you use the more common approach:

First, let the switch go to GND, not 5V. You might want to invert your detection logic, therefore.

Then there are two possible solutions:

- You set `GPPU` in the `OPTION` register to `0`. This enables the built-in weak pull-up resistors. This gives the floating pin a "high" level.
- You add an external pull-up resistor, a value of some kiloohms suffices.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the pull-down resistor, I have dealt with that before, seems I just neglected that part since I'm not very experienced and very frustrated with not understanding and not finding answers easily. I have also read the article in the answer suggested by @Lundin. I will try this set up in a couple of days since I'm in the middle of some exams. I will reach out to you here as soon as possible.

Comment: The GPPU register set to 0 does not do the job, neither the pull-up resistor. The state of the GP0 remains HIGH, also the GP1 seems to not read or not react to the switch.

Comment: I also made sure the GP1 pin is not shorted and switch the detection logic as you said, connecting it to GND. Either way, pull-up and pull-down resistor don't seem to make GP1 read the state.